# Assign struct pointer to a struct pointer inside of null struct pointer

Tags: c++

This question might be stupid, but I've been wondering what happens if you have:

```
struct List {
    int x;
    List *next;
};
struct List *start = nullptr;
struct List *tmp = start->next;
```

What happens to tmp?

I've tried compiling it and I get no errors. If I output address of `start` I get 0, but if I output `tmp` I get nothing.

Comment: You dereference a null pointer (start), so you have undefined behaviour. After you do `start->next` you can't reason about your program.

Comment: That should be nullpointer access. I dont know how you are not getting run time error!

Comment: @Mukesh Undefined behaviour does not guarantee a runtime error.

Comment: But segmentation fault may happen.

Comment: @Ebrahim _Anything_ may happen. Or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

On the line `struct List *tmp = start->next;` since we know that `start == nullptr` you are dereferencing a nullptr value.  This is UB (undefined behavior) and as such "anything" can happen.

Answer (score -1):

It is an undefined behavior. After multiple execusion it may output a different result or maybe a segmentation fault.